# Converting float to 32-bit hexadecimal C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Could anyone please tell me if there is any code to convert floating point number to hexadecimal format?

For Ex: float num = 70.482 and hexadecimal function should return 428CF6C9.

If there are any codes already done before on this, kindly link me.

Cheers.

Comment: Why `70.482` should return `428CF6C9`? What is the logic?

Comment: That's what the online converter returned the value as.

http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Comment: Did you look at the JavaScript for that page? You would need to translate to c++, but at least you can look at their algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this is the floattohex conversion i use.. *(it also performs a bit swap, if you dont need this take it out)*

```
CString Class::FloatToHex(float* yourfloat)
{
unsigned char ch[4];
Cstring output;

memcpy(ch,yourfloat,sizeof(float));
output.Format("%X%X%X%X",ch[3],ch[2],ch[1],ch[0]);

return output;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this making the dangerous and unchecked assumption that `sizeof(float)` does not exceed 4, and would otherwise trash your memory?

Answer (score 17):

You can just trivially write that yourself:

```
float x;
const unsigned char * pf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x);

for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
{
  // ith byte is pf[i]
  // e.g. printf("0x02X ", pf[i]);
}
```

In fact, you can do that to obtain the binary representation of *any* (standard-layout*) variable.

<sub>*) thanks, @R. Martinho Fernandes!</sub>

If you decide to try this on a `long double` (or rather, an 80-bit extended precision float), beware that that has only 10 bytes, but is padded to 12 or 16 on x86/x64, respectively.

Comment: +1 And you don't need to worry about long doubles if you're using MSVC :-)

Comment: Not *any* variable though. In C++11 the value is unspecified if either the source or the destination pointer types is not a standard-layout type. I'm pretty sure there's some similar restriction in C++03.

Comment: will the byte ordering of the architecture effect the order of bytes which are printed ?

Comment: @phoxis: Yes! This will expose all the gory details of the implementation ... padding of structs, most importantly. R. Martinho: What exactly do you mean? Which part of this cast is unspecified?

Comment: @Kerrek: not *this* cast. But you said you could do this to get the binary representation of *any* variable. You can't for non-standard-layout types.

Comment: @R. Martinho: Interesting. Can you give a quick counter example and say what goes wrong?

Comment: Well, if `A` is, for example, a type with a virtual member function and given `A a; auto b = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);` the value of `b` is unspecified. It bet in pretty much all implementations you will get to see the vptrs and all that, though. Oh, and the guarantee that you can roundtrip is still valid: `auto x = reinterpret_cast<const A*>(b);` will give you the original pointer, even though the intermediate value is unspecified.

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but I am a bit new to working with reinterpret_cast and was not able to use this in my program. But really thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Nerds: Feel free to go with another answer, or to ask for more details, but be aware that you accepted an answer that's broken and dangerous.

Comment: By looping from 0 to 3 you flip the result from left to right! Instead of "428CF6C9" you will get "C9F68C42".

Comment: I'm just reading up on strict aliasing and it seems that this method is potentially dangerous: https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
union float_bits {
    unsigned int i;
    float f;
} bits;
```

Assign the floating point number into `bits.f`, and then interpret the whole number as an unsigned integer and read it with `bits.i`. By doing this the floating point representation bytes will stay intact, and no implicit type conversion will be done as it would be when assigning a float to an int type variable. In this case we assume that the size of integer is same as the size of float.

Or you can do:

```
float f;
char *c = (char *) &f;
```

And then access the individual bytes of `f` through `c[index]`.

Comment: that is assuming sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)

Comment: That's also undefined behaviour.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: right, i went the c way. corrected now.

Comment: @Kerrek SB While the union example is technically undefined, it's an often used idiom and quite certainly will be supported by any compiler and every other solution is ugly and unhandy. I'd still mention it (and use it myself, bad me) but a warning is certainly in place I agree..

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 70.482f;
int i = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f));
printf("%08x\n", i);
```

Comment: @Kerrek: What is the subtlety that allows the casting to `const unsigned char` that you did, and not `int`?  (I believe you, I just don't see it)

Comment: The difference is that casting to `char` is allowed, but casting to other types isn't :-)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `union`:

```
union FloatToChar {
    float f;
    char  c[sizeof(float)];
};

FloatToChar x;
x.f = 10.42f;
for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(float); i++)
    printf( "%X", x.c[i] );
```

you could do this vice-versa, too.

Comment: This seems to assume that `sizeof (float)` is 4 - can you justify that?

Comment: @TobySpeight,  I changed the code to cater for all cases of sizeof(float)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use sprintf() : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

For example,

```
char out[8];
float myFloat = 70.482;
sprintf(out,"%X",myFloat);
```

Comment: Yea, we tried that. Did not work the way we wanted it to. Did not return the correct value.

Comment: Careful: `float` gets promoted to `double` when passed through variadic arguments!